# Threading or Task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently picking up C# again and developping a simple application that sends broadcast messages and when received shown on a Windows Form.

I have a discovery class with two threads, one that broadcasts every 30 seconds, the other thread listens on a socket. It is in a thread because of the blocking call:

```
                if (listenSocket.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectRead))
```

The first thread works much like a timer in a class library, it broadcasts the packet and then sleeps for 30 seconds.

Now in principle it works fine, when a packet is received I throw it to an event and the Winform places it in a list. The problems start with the form though because of the main UI thread requiring Invoke. Now I only have two threads and to me it doesn't seem to be the most effective in the long run becoming a complex thin when the number of threads will grow.

I have explored the Tasks but these seem to be more orientated at a once off long running task (much like the background worker for a form).

Most threading examples I find all report to the console and do not have the problems of Invoke and locking of variables.

As i'm using .NET 4.5 should I move to Tasks or stick to the threads?

Comment: Could you describe your case a bit more - I am not sure if I understand what is your main worry.

Answer (score 1):

Async programming will still delegate some aspects of your application to a different thread (threadpool) if you try to update the GUI from such a thread you are going to have similar problems as you have today with regular threads.

However there are many techniques in async await that allow you to delegate to a background thread, and yet put a kind off wait point saying please continue here on the GUI thread when you are finished with that operation which effectively allows you to update the GUI thread without invoke, and have a responsive GUI. I am talking about configureAwait. But there are other techniques as well.

If you don't know async await mechanism yet, this will take you some investment of your time to learn all these new things. But you'll find it very rewarding.
But it is up to you to decide if you are willing to spend a few days learning and experimenting with a technology that is new to you.

Google around a bit on async await, there are some excellent articles from Stephen Cleary for instance http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: I actually did read this article, this would solve the Invoke, but how would I go into what I now use as the "endless" loop for broadcasting. Later on I will not always have a Winforms application, but will write to a database most likely and then view in a webpage. Otherwise I will hve a publick property on my class that will expose the List<> and have a lock mechanism in the Get ancestor to make it thread safe.

Comment: Webrequests, database access and the like, you will find that the api's have async methods that you can use. It means a redesign of what you have today. It is not a walk in the park.

Comment: This is my confusion, my thread will throw an event, up to here it is fine. The db i will use with EF and async. Im just not sure how Task can replace my endless loop thread which is a timer essentially. At one point i would have to call the broadcast routine on a regular basis. Should each property on the class with the thread use locks to protect them?

Comment: The whole notion of async and wait is about concurrency not about multithreading. Multithreading is a form of concurrency. With async and wait you don't see the threads anymore, even though they are there, and you cannot use locks. But maybe you should post more concrete questions perhaps with your first attempts. People can help here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you're worried about scalability you should probably start off with an approach that scales easily. `ThreadPool` would work nice. Tasks are based on `ThreadPool` as well and they allow for a bit more complex situations like tasks/threads firing in a sequence (also based on condition), synchronization etc. In your case (server and client) this seems unneeded.

Secondly it looks to me that you are worried about a bottleneck scenario where more than one thread will try to access a common resource like UI or DB etc. With DBs - don't worry they can handle multiple access well. But in case of UI or other not-multithread-friendly resource you have to manage parallel access yourself. I would suggest something like [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a nice way to implement "many producers, one consumer" pattern. This way you could have multiple threads adding stuff and just one thread reading it from the collection and passing it on the the single-threaded resource like UI.

BTW, Tasks can also be long running i.e. run loops. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.